# how do i read a text file in line-by-line using Python when the formatting is specific

Tags: python, file, parsing, readlines

how do i read a text file in line-by-line using Python when the formatting is specific?  My data is "space delimited and looks like this with spaces between each line. In reality there are no blank lines, nor is there an "end" card:

```
The_Ark.top                                 0   -37.89541   37.89541    0.00000 449.75055 
8 
0.00000     0.00000     29  -37.59748     0.04690   26  -37.89541   449.75055   26 
-0.19951   449.70273     26   -0.15660     4.48848   29  -34.20844     4.80188   26 
-33.71897   443.53000     26   -0.45357   443.32349   26    0.00000     0.00000    0
{possibly more lines ... to the end}
```

data on line 1: filename, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax

data on line 2: number of points in file

data on line 3: x(0), y(0), pen(0), x(1), y(1), pen(1), x(2), y(2), pen(2)

data on line 4: follows like line 3... to end

note: there may not be three x,y,pen combos per line.  could be 1, 2, or 3.

so far I have the following:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np

filepath = 'The_Ark.top'
with open(filepath) as file:
    data = file.readlines()

lineCount = len(data)

# parse first line
firstLine = data[0]
words = firstLine.split()
objectName = words[0]
mirrorCard = int(words[1])
if mirrorCard == 0:
    mirrorFlag = "True"
else:
    mirrorFlag = "False"
    
xMin = float(words[2])
xMax = float(words[3])
yMin = float(words[4])
yMax = float(words[5])

xCenter = (xMax - xMin)/2 + xMin
yCenter = (yMax - yMin)/2 + yMin

# parse second line
secondLine = data[1]
words = secondLine.split()
numPoints = int(words[0])

# parse remaining lines
.
.
.
# having trouble here...
.
.
.

    
print ("\nRead %d lines\n" % lineCount)

print ("File Name: " + objectName + " and mirror set to: " + mirrorFlag)
print ("xMin: %7.3f  xMax: %7.3f" % (xMin, xMax))
print ("yMin: %7.3f  yMax: %7.3f" % (yMin, yMax))
print ("x Center: %7.3f  y Center: %7.3f" % (xCenter, yCenter))
```

Comment: I would omit the line numbers from your data file description. Confusing if they are really there or not.

Comment: Is this file space-delimited or tab? Whatever generated this format didn't do you any favors!

Comment: To parse the remaining lines, you can start with `for line in data[2:]:` Does the last line say `end` by itself?

Comment: Why do you need to use `secondLine.split()`? It's just one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all of the points from line 3 and beyond in a list of lists.

You just need to replace:

```
# parse remaining lines
.
.
.
# having trouble here...
.
.
.
```

with:

```
line = list()
points = list()

for i in range(2,len(data)):
    line.extend(data[i].split())

points = [line[x:x+3] for x in range(0, len(line),3)]
```

or if you want to store each of them as separate lists, you can do the following:

```
x = list()
y = list()
pen = list()

for i in range(2,len(data)):
    line = data[i].split()
    for j in range(len(line)):
        if j%3 == 0:
            x.append(line[j])
        elif j%3 == 1:
            y.append(line[j])
        else:
            pen.append(line[j])
```

You can make plots easily this way.

Comment: Why make the huge list just to split it up? Just make the list of lists in the `for` loop.

Comment: how do I separate "points" into X-array, Y-array, PEN-array? Eventually I want to send this data to a screen to plot it.

Comment: @ArtVanHouten I have updated my answer so you can now plot the data more easily

Comment: @ArtVanHouten No problem. If this works for you, I would appreciate you upvoting and marking it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def regular_line_parse(data, line_number):
    line_index = line_number - 1
    scope_data = data[line_index]
    line_parts = scope_data.split()
    cluster_size = len(line_parts) / 3

    X, Y, PEN = [], [], []
    for i in range(cluster_size):
        X.append(float(line_parts[3 * i]))
        Y.append(float(line_parts[3 * i  + 1]))
        PEN.append(float(line_parts[3 * i + 2]))
   
    return X, Y, PEN
```

This function should help you in the trouble area that you marked. It parses the specific line number of data(line number > 2 in your case) and returns each type of value as a list so that you could save them as you’d wish.

Comment: so, I put the function at the "top" of my code? how do you call it? I see the functionality of what you provided, but I'm a Python novice and am unsure how to implement...

Comment: Yes, put the function definition at the top of your code. Then, create a for loop in range of your number of lines (aka len(data)). for the first and the second line, your own solution works since those two lines format differ from the rest. Call this function and pass data and the line_number(your loop counter + 1) to get Xs, Ys, pens of each line. I suggest you take a few minutes to get used to the syntax of how loops and functions and other basic elements work in python, just some basic examples from W3Schools would suffice.

Comment: understood, but when I run the above within the function I get X, Y, and PEN, but outside the function in the main program I have no data...

Comment: This is how you should call a function that returns outputs.

`X, Y, PEN = regular_line_parse(data, i + 1)`

Comment: you should save them in another data structure that stacks all of these values for you since these X, Y, and PEN lists are overwritten with every iteration of your main loop.

Comment: hmmmm - if I print those values within the function all of them are there, but in the main program all I get is the last vales...

Comment: I see, they get overwritten in the main program.  What "data structure" would I use that stacks all the intermediate values?  a ".append" like you used in the function?

Comment: I got it.  x, Xpnts = [] then after calling your function returning Xpnts  I just do x.append(Xpnts), etc. for all values.  works pretty well.  Thanks.